# Tab bar Controller.... Second View Controller doesn't have tab bar items?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a `tab bar controller` that points to several `story board` references.

One of the references points to a story board (`SC1`) with two `view controllers`.  On `VC1`, the tab bar appears, yet on `VC2` the tab bar does not when I segue to it programmatically.  Perhaps it's more accurate to say the `tab bar items` don't because a light grey bar does appear to be at the bottom of the view.

I have another story board (`SC2`) with a similar setup yet the tab bar appears on both `VC1` and `VC2`.  In this case I `segue` by clicking on a `tableview cell`.

In both cases I segue from `VC1` to `VC2` using a Show (e.g. Push) segue.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be created as a relationship to the external storyboard reference. the storyboard's VC you'll be referencing must have a tab bar item in it to show app. Plus you can also try create a tab bar controller and add them in code (I have done that in the past).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a lack of understanding of Tab Bar Controller and the relationship with Navigation View Controllers.

I assumed every child vc embedded in a Tab Bar Controller would display the tabs. In other words..

```
Tab vc 
...vc1 
.....vc2
```

Tab vc only sees vc1.  The answer is in the Navigation Controller.

The first vc must be embedded in a Navigation Controller.  That vc and all other child vc's go onto the Nav Controller stack... When you call it, every child vc knows that it is embedded in a Tab Vc and will display the tabs.